# Anonymous reviewer disclosed his identity. Should I thank him by name?

Tags: peer-review, acknowledgement

A "friendly" reviewer purposely disclosed his identity to me (the author) during a previous round of reviews of a paper that was not published back then. However, he helped me to make the article better. If I publish the paper now, should I thank him by name or as an anonymous reviewer?

Comment: Just for fun, you could do both: "We thank an anonymous reviewer, Dr. John Doe".

Comment: See here for a quick caution: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26736/how-to-respond-to-my-name-being-included-in-acknowledgements-of-incorrect-mislea especially Pete's answer (not that I think the question title applies to your case). I don't think it's always necessary to ask permission for acknowledgements (for example, I wouldn't expect technicians working in a lab who don't qualify for authorship to be asked), but probably a good idea to check whether someone minds if you acknowledge them by name in your case.

Comment: And actually this one is even more directly relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-it-necessary-to-ask-permission-before-including-someone-in-the-acknowledgemen

Comment: He won't have any problem with being associated with my findings, my doubt was about the ethics of naming him when I am not supposed to know who he is.

Comment: My point was that it might be a good courtesy to let *him* make that decision/determination. You said in another comment that the reveal was not accidental, so I don't think it's correct to say you aren't supposed to know who it is.

Comment: @Bryan Krause Yes, I will let him decide. I meant that I am not supposed to know according to the blind peer-review system.

Comment: You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/what-should-an-editor-do-if-the-authors-have-guessed-who-the-reviewers-are

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Or you could thank him twice: "We thank an anonymous reviewer, as well as Dr. John Doe.".

Comment: I think thanking him twice sends the false message that those were two different reviews.

Comment: do you have his contact information to ask?

Comment: Yes, I do, and I will.

Answer (score 46):

You can thank him by name for making helpful suggestions for improvement. You don't need to say that the comments were during a formal review.

Alternatively, he should be thanked as an anonymous reviewer.

I would, personally, prefer the first alternative. The publisher might also prefer it if you are using the name.

Comment: Exactly; I would thank him in the same way you would thank a colleague who you personally showed the paper to and who gave useful feedback.

Comment: The best way might be to find out how the reviewer feels about it. Ask "Can I thank you by name in the paper?".

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, Good catch. Probably an answer.

Answer (score 23):

Email him first and thank him that way before disclosing him in the article. He may have inadvertently revealed himself or there was an administrative error that revealed him? Good to check just in case.

Most people would prefer a personal email anyway rather than a mention in an article. Though both is great too.

Comment: No, it was not inadvertently.

Comment: "Most people would prefer a personal email anyway rather than a mention in an article" -- why not "in addition to" instead of "rather than"?

Comment: Good point John. Changed my answer

Comment: @John Coleman Do you really think so? At least young academics with not enough publications yet, I think, would love to be mentioned in papers...

Comment: Good point. Maybe people do appreciate it. Just haven't had anyone talk about it and I don't see many mentions that are useful.

Comment: Never really had a colleague or anyone get excited about an article mention or ever refer to it. But maybe my circle is biased and I am happy to concur with your comment. Everyone get appreciated and feel appreciated in different ways...

Comment: I would like to add that I would try to avoid any side-channel communication between you and the reviewer which does not go through the publisher. I must admin I cannot find this any more, but I do remember instructions for authors at some journal(s) stating that authors should not contact (potential) reviewers, and vice versa.

Comment: In many fields, reviewers have the opportunity to reveal themselves apparently - https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97778/how-to-acknowledge-an-anonymous-referee-who-identified-themselves/97812#97812

Comment: bers - I asked a question based on your comment. I hope you don't mind - https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137751/are-there-journals-that-prevent-authors-from-contacting-reviewers

Comment: @bers He (as far as I know) is not a reviewer for the current submission of my article, so we can communicate freely now.

Comment: @PhilosopherOfScience oh, I see. So my comment doesn't really apply, but apparently it sparked another question. Nice!

Answer (score 19):

Echoing Wolfgang Bangerth's comment:

Anytime you plan on thanking someone in the acknowledgements to a paper, it is not a bad idea to contact them first to let them know what you plan to say.  This gives them a heads up and a chance to object in case for some reason they don't want to be thanked, as well as a double-check that you have written their name correctly and so forth.  (It's not just a matter of spelling - for instance, some people sign their emails with one variant of their name, and their papers with another.)

So I would do that in this case:

> Dear Professor Schmoe,
>
> I wanted to write to thank you for your helpful comments on my paper "On the reticulation of splines".  I really appreciate you taking the time to review the paper so carefully.
>
> I am planning to write in the acknowledgements: "I thank Joseph Schmoe for suggestions regarding the material in Section 5."  Is that how you prefer your name to be written?  I can also list you as "an anonymous reviewer" if you would prefer that.

If he agrees, then I see no problem with mentioning his name.

Answer (score 7):

I think strictly speaking the right answer here is to thank them anonymously. If you thank them by name, you are revealing more than they themselves disclosed - they may, in principle, by willing to disclose their identity towards the authors but not towards the general public.

That said, I find the general practice of thanking anonymous reviewers to be a bit silly - *every* peer reviewed paper has had (usually anonymous) reviewers, and people tend to thank them whether they have actually made good comments or not. I think nothing is lost to anybody if we just stopped this custom entirely (and, ideally, start implementing some *actual* benefits for peer reviewing).

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, let's just say there are definitely cases where said anonymous reviewers should not be thanked.  So if people only thanked them when they really got something useful out of it, it might be a good change.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes. *(Asking permission is good, too.)*

I agree with [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/137696), but responding to OP's comment, "He won't have any problem with being associated with my findings, my doubt was about the ethics of naming him when I am not supposed to know who he is.":

I should think the most ethical perspective is to *make sure* to name him. Otherwise, it might seem like you are hiding the relationship. I personally think disclosing all potential conflicts of interest (if that's the ethical dilemma, here) is the best way to avoid both deception and the appearance of deception.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that reviewers should not disclose their identities to authors, ... I'd think that you should *not* play into the situation by publicizing the fact that the reviewer did so.

The potential problem is that if we have many precedents for this, then some people might start *expecting* reviewers to disclose their identities, possibly with the purpose of getting a co-authorship (otherwise deserved or not), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If the reviewer went above and beyond the call of duty, I think a thanks by name is entirely appropriate.  I know of at least one example of exactly that situation where the referee is thanked by name.